# 'Kickchart gem' show monthly chart by selecting the momth and set by default current month to show

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, chartkick

I have this code in my controller filter by month :

```
@posts = Post.by_month(params[:selected_month])
```

now I need to set current month as default value in case of nil ????

Comment: There are several answers on StackOverflow to help with default parameters for Ruby: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=ruby+default+parameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you already implemented that method at your Model.

You can get the name of the current month with:

`Date.today.strftime("%B")`

So at your code:

```
month = params[:selected_month] ? params[:selected_month] : Date.today.strftime("%B")
@posts = Post.by_month(month)
```

This should be work if your method by_month search records by month name

If your method search by month number then change `Date.today.strftime("%B")` by `Date.today.strftime("%m")`

Comment: Thank you Oscar Luza I used some of you code and created if statement in case nil and worked great:                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
    if (params[:selected_month]).nil?
        #posts = Post.by_month(Date.today.strftime("%m"))
    else
      #posts = Post.by_month(params[:desierd_month])
    end

Comment: You're welcome!, Thank you for selecting my answer as correct